# ASP.NET MVC passing mapping object arrays to controller paramaters from jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, parameter-passing

I currently have a bunch of methods in my controllers which take selected records from table rows.

So I might have something like

```
var ids = [];
var prices = [];
var customers = [];

$selectedRow.each(function() {
    ids.push($(this).find('.id').text());
    prices.push($(this).find('.price').text());
    customers.push($(this).find('.customer').text());
});

$.post(....) // AJAX call to controller method
```

And in the controller I end up with

```
public ActionResult DoSomething(int[] ids, double[] prices, string[] customers) { ... }
```

which is just a bit messy to deal with using iterators.

What I'd really like is to have

```
Class Foo
{
    int id;
    double price;
    string customer;
}
```

and be able to receive

```
public ActionResult DoSomething(List<Foo> foos) { ... }
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit hacky but here's an example:

```
// query array: construct this as usual
var array = [{ id: '1', name: 'name 1' }, { id: '2', name: 'name 2'}];

// map the array into an array of DOM hidden fields
var query = $.map(array, function (element, index) {
    return [$(document.createElement('input'))
                    .attr('type', 'hidden')
                    .attr('name', 'foos[' + index + '].id')
                    .val(element.id),
                $(document.createElement('input'))
                    .attr('type', 'hidden')
                    .attr('name', 'foos[' + index + '].name')
                    .val(element.name)
                ];
});

// construct a form
var form = $(document.createElement('form'));
$(query).appendTo(form);

$.ajax({
    url: '<%: Url.Action("Test") %>',
    data: form.serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (result) {
        alert('success');
    }
});
```

This will successfully bind to a controller action of the form:

```
public ActionResult Test(IEnumerable<Foo> foos) 
{
    ...    
}
```

where Foo:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Remark: All this is not necessary if you [configure your controller action to accept JSON](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx). In ASP.NET MVC 3 this is automatically included in the framework.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is.

Look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616559/default-model-binder-and-complex-types-that-include-a-list) for details.

Also these resources can help you:

- [ASP.Net MVC2 Custom Templates Loading via Ajax and Model Updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317416/asp-net-mvc2-custom-templates-loading-via-ajax-and-model-updating/3319853#3319853)
- [Model Binding within a Model Binder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709162/model-binding-within-a-model-binder)
- [Model Binders in ASP.NET MVC - Part 2](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Model_Binders_in_ASPNET_MVC__Part_2.aspx)

Comment: I'm not trying to model bind to a form though, those solutions won't work with jQuery submitted values will they?

Comment: Yes they will if you use `("#form").serialize()` when submitting the form itself

Answer (score 0):

Phil Haack wrote a blog post on this too: [Model Binding To A List](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx)

Also, MVC 3's model binder will support JSON post data I think - but this is obviously not going to help you today :(

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the view is not being returned. Its showing the alert in the call back